# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand

Tags: sql-server

I am using this code to populate a table in a database:

```
var brandsData = File.ReadAllText(path + @"\SeedData\brands.json");

var brands = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProductBrand>>(brandsData);

foreach (var item in brands)
{
    context.ProductBrands.Add(item); <-- error executing this line
}
```

This is the log output.  I cannot see what would be giving the error.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (59ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (Size = 4000), @p8='?' (DbType = Int32), @p9='?' (Size = 4000), @p10='?' (DbType = Int32), @p11='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   INSERT INTO [ProductBrands] ([Id], [Name])
>   VALUES (@p0, @p1),
>   (@p2, @p3),

Comment: The error message seems to be cut. Isn't there more information on the error after the query?

Comment: If you are adding a lot of records, consider using `DbContext.AddRange()` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrange?view=efcore-3.1 it might help for performance and errors.

Comment: I found the error by looking at the log output. I was defining the id twice.

Comment: @which log output?

Comment: Probably related to issue when exception is not bubled up https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24530